# Mimic Email-to-Case in a test class

Tags: unit-test, email2case

I'm writing a method that marks a case as a "Duplicate" if two or more email2case addresses are referenced in the To Address of the incoming email. However, I can't figure out the best way to test this. I know that I can just create the cases and then associate the email messages, but I would really like to verify that this will work correctly with email2case.

```
public static void isCaseDuplicate(List<EmailMessage> emailMessageList){
        List<EmailServicesAddress> email2CaseAddresses = [SELECT IsActive, LocalPart, EmailDomainName FROM EmailServicesAddress where Function.FunctionName='EmailToCase' and isactive = true];
        List<String> email2CaseAddressStrings = new List<String>();
        List<String> toAddressStrings = new List<String>();
        Set<String> dedupedAddress = new Set<String>();
        List<String> ccAddressStrings = new List<String>();
        List<Case> updateCases = new List<Case>();
        for(EmailServicesAddress email2Case : email2CaseAddresses){
            email2CaseAddressStrings.add(email2case.LocalPart);
        }
        system.debug('Email2Case Strings are: ' + email2CaseAddressStrings);
        integer countofE2c = 0; 
        system.debug('Initialize count should be 0: ' + countofE2c);
        for(EmailMessage emailRecord : emailMessageList){
            system.debug(emailRecord.Headers);
            if(emailRecord.ParentId != NULL && emailRecord.Incoming && string.isBlank(emailRecord.Headers)){
             system.debug('Email is Associated to Case');
                toAddressStrings = emailRecord.ToAddress.split(';');
                dedupedAddress.addAll(toAddressStrings);
                system.debug('To address size; ' + toAddressStrings.size()); 
                for(String addressString : dedupedAddress){
                    String trimmedString = addressString.subStringBefore('@');
                    system.debug('String is: ' + trimmedString.trim());
                    system.debug('Does email2case contain string? ' + email2CaseAddressStrings.contains(trimmedString.trim()));
                    if(email2CaseAddressStrings.contains(trimmedString.trim())){
                        countofE2c++;
                        system.debug('E2C Count is: ' + countofE2C);
                        
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            if(countofE2c > 1){
                Case updateCase = new Case();
                updateCase.Id = emailRecord.ParentId; 
                updateCase.Potential_Duplicate__c = TRUE; 
                updateCases.add(updateCase);
                
            }
        }
        update updateCases;

        
        
            
    }
```

Saw one person recommended initializing EmailToCase the way you would an Apex Email Service but that didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to simulate the way E2C works under the covers. It looks like you don't care whether the email has attachments.

- The running user should be the user defined in Support Settings (Case Automation user)
- Insert `Case`(s) using the same field values that your E2C setup has configured (Origin, Recordtype, Priority, Owner)
- If important to you, you can coerce the assignment rules to be run when you insert the `Case`
- Insert `EmailMessage`(s) with the fields set as you need to for testing. The `EmailMessage.ParentId` will reference the mocked `Case`(s)

*A more advanced pattern would be to convert your code to use the [UnitOfWork pattern](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_learn_uow_principles) and then you could dispense with actual DML entirely in your testmethod as you would only need to verify that `registerDirty` was called for each Case that should be updated given mocked, not DML'd `EmailMessage`*